# Can I use python 3.7 with Django for production?

Tags: django, python-3.7

I want to use django channels, apache(modwsgi),redis , are these features are supported in 3.7.
I have this problem since I want to use these features for production as well be updated with the support and also performance

Comment: Why would you think they would not be supported?

Answer (score 3):

According to [django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django), These django version supported by python versions:

```
Django version  Python versions
1.11            2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 (added in 1.11.17)
2.0             3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7
2.1, 2.2        3.5, 3.6, 3.7
```

So, you are able to use Python 3.7 for production.